# Linux server fails file copy over 2.0 GB

Tags: linux, rsync

When using RSYNC, CP or DD on Linux to a Windows SMB share the file gets to 2.0 GB of 6.3 GB and errors stating file is too large.

This has started since disabling SMB1 on the Windows share.  I have re-mapped the share using SMB 2.1 in `fstab` on Linux.

```
Linux SERVERNAME 3.8.13-68.2.2.el6uek.x86_64 #2 SMP Tue May 12 15:10:51 PDT 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 by Andrew Tridgell, Wayne Davison, and others.
Web site: http://rsync.samba.org/
Capabilities:
    64-bit files, 64-bit inums, 64-bit timestamps, 64-bit long ints,
    socketpairs, hardlinks, symlinks, IPv6, batchfiles, inplace,
    append, ACLs, xattrs, iconv, symtimes

rsync comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.  This is free software, and you
are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.  See the GNU
General Public Licence for details.
```

---

I have tried `--partial-dir` and it does place the file in the partial directory but when you attempt to run it again to resume it, the file does not resume.  It starts over.

```
[root@SERVERNAME dpdump]# rsync -av --progress --partial-dir=.rsync-partial /u01/dpdump /BackupFolder
sending incremental file list
dpdump/
dpdump/PD20181119.dmp
  2084536320  31%  113.23MB/s    0:00:39
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/BackupFolder/dpdump/PD20181119.dmp": File too large (27)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(301) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (303 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

---

I have tried using `block-size` and `protocol` from another SO post, still doesn't work.

```
[root@SERVERNAME dpdump]# rsync -av --progress --partial-dir=.rsync-partial --block-size=108485760 --protocol=29  /u01/dpdump /BackupFolder
building file list ...
220 files to consider
dpdump/
dpdump/PD20181119.dmp
  1998913536  29%  187.58MB/s    0:00:24
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4092 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/BackupFolder/dpdump/PD20181119.dmp": File too large (27)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(301) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (577 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

---

I have tried `append-verify` as the manpage recommends but it does not resume the file, it overwrites and starts from 0.

```
[root@SERVERNAME dpdump]# rsync -av --progress --append-verify  /u01/dpdump /BackupFolder
sending incremental file list
dpdump/
dpdump/PD20181119.dmp
  2147549183  32%   33.88MB/s    0:02:10
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/BackupFolder/dpdump/PD20181119.dmp": File too large (27)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(301) [receiver=3.0.6]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (302 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
```

---

Trying to do a 1GB file using `dd` works.  Trying to use a 3GB file using `dd` does not.  It stops at 2.1 GB.

```
# dd if=/dev/zero of=/BackupFoldertest.img count=1 bs=1G
1+0 records in
1+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 13.8795 s, 77.4 MB/s

# dd if=/dev/zero of=/BackupFoldertest.img count=1 bs=3G
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
2147479552 bytes (2.1 GB) copied, 28.625 s, 75.0 MB/s
#
```

**Previous rsync's that worked are shown.  Stopped when I disabled SMB1 on the Windows share.  The 12/10/2018 ones are the ones where it broke.**

[image]

Comment: Put the output of `rsync --version` in your question. I wonder if it was compiled with 64-bit support. Can you also include the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Can you just copy the file using cp? also try `dd if=/dev/zero of=/BackupFolder/test.img count=1 bs=1G` and post the result.

Comment: @davidbaumann:  cp File too large.  dd:  1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 13.8795 s, 77.4 MB/s.  Changed it to 3G from 1G and it stopped at 2.1GB copied.

Comment: Added your details @Bert

Comment: So it's not an rsync problem.

Comment: How exactly (as in, `fstab` and `/proc/mounts` output) is the share mounted?  It sounds an awful lot like you disabled the wrong SMB protocol version.

Comment: @womble `fstab` : `//SERVERNAME/Backup /BackupFolder cifs vers=2.1,dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0755,uid=500,gid=500 0 0`

Comment: some random guesses:
is the share itself fat formatted? can you reproduce enabling SMB1 = it works again?
qoute "This has started since disabling SMB1 on the Windows share."
how did you disable it? via mount option on linux side or from the windows side?

what does the logs on the server say?

do you happen to have not enough space left on the share? something like a logrotated file still beeing written to?

Comment: @DennisNolte It's NTFS.  Enterprise policy, can't re-enable SMB1 to test it.  Disabled it on the Windows side only.  1.7TB free on space.  Not a log rotated file.  Nothing in the windows logs.  Don't know what to check on Linux.

Comment: To rule out already fixed kernel bugs, etc., you should update the system. It appears to be some three years behind on updates.

Comment: `dd if=/dev/zero of=/BackupFoldertest.img count=1 bs=3G` is a useless test.  The resulting `write()` size of 2147479552 (note that `dd` says it's a *partial* block with the `0+1 records` in the output) is because [Linux truncates read/write calls to MAX_RW_COUNT bytes](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/search?q=MAX_RW_COUNT), which is [`#define`'d to be 2GB - 4KB](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d81f50bd34646d8373b989e55180c0fc9af94e0b/include/linux/fs.h#L2299), or exactly the result of 2147479552 bytes.  Use a `bs=4k` or similar that is more representative of what `rsync` does.

Answer (score 1):

Could be a filesystem issue on the target disk (FAT16 format?). On disks, the maximum size of a volume or file and the maximum number of files per volume depend on the file system used to format the volume. https://www.genie9.com/Support/KB/KnowledgeArticle.aspx?KBID=113